# How does list initialization work? Is there any overloading done?

Tags: c++, list, initialization

I came across this type of initialization and was curious to know how it works:

`list<int> a = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};`

Comment: That's using `std::initializer_list`, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/operator%3D for example for `std::list`.

Comment: The iniitalization list becomes a [`std::initializer_list`](https://www.google.com/search?q=cppreference%20std%3A%3Ainiitalizer_list), which is passed to the correspondig [`std::list` constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/list).

Comment: On an unrelated note, the default container should always be `std::vector`. Unless you have specific requirements that prohibits it.

Answer (score -1):

This is equivaent to:

```cs
b[5] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

```cs
{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

is syntactic sugar for

```cs
a[0] = 1 ... a[4] = 5
```

conversion

```cs
a = (list<int>) b
```

Comment: No it is not an array. It is a list being initialized by initializerlist. The constructor accepting the initializer list will enumerate the items in that list and append them to the list.